# NextJs 14 middleware redirect issue: User Keeps getting redirected to /login after successful Sign-In

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js 14 project and facing a middleware issue.

After a user successfully signs in, they are redirected to the /home page. At this point, the user is logged in and should be able to access protected pages like /dashboard. However, when clicking to navigate to /dashboard, they are instead redirected back to the /login page.

**Recreate the issue**
Video is available on github

https://github.com/anni1236012/nextjsMiddleware

**Observed Behavior:**

**Initial Access:** On the first visit, unauthenticated users are correctly redirected to the /login page.

**Post-Login:** After logging in, any attempt to access /dashboard results in a redirection back to /login.

**Delayed Navigation:** Interestingly, after a few minutes post-login, the user can successfully navigate to /dashboard without being redirected.

**Troubleshooting Done:**
I checked the network tab in the browser's developer tools, but there's no request being made to /dashboard when the redirection occurs.

**middleware.ts**

```js
import { jwtVerify } from "jose";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/login", "/logout", "/dashboard", "/chat", "/team"],
};

// Defined here because it was not fetching from .env
const JWT_SECRET = "mysecret";

// verify if user is authenticated
const isAuthenticated = async (sessionToken: string) => {
  try {
    const userSession = await jwtVerify(
      sessionToken,
      new TextEncoder().encode(JWT_SECRET)
    );
    return userSession;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const sessionToken = request.cookies.get("sessionToken")?.value || null;

    if (request.nextUrl.pathname === "/logout") {
      const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url));
      response.cookies.set({
        name: "sessionToken",
        value: "",
        path: "/",
        maxAge: 0,
      });

      return response;
    }

    // If there is no sessionToken, redirect to the login page
    if (!sessionToken) {
      console.log("No sessionToken");
      // If the user is already on the login page, continue
      if (request.nextUrl.pathname === "/login") {
        return NextResponse.next();
      }
      // Redirect the user to login page if not logged in
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (e) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
  }
}
```

**Navbar**

```js
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useGlobalContextProvider } from "@/app/context/globalContext";
export default function Navbar() {
  const { session, setSession } = useGlobalContextProvider();
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="sticky inset-0 flex justify-end p-4">
        <ul className=" flex gap-4">
          <li>
            <Link href="/" className="hover:underline">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/team" className="hover:underline">
              Team
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/chat" className="hover:underline">
              Chat
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/dashboard" className="hover:underline">
              Dashboard
            </Link>
          </li>

          {session && (
            <li>
              <Link
                href="/logout"
                className="p-2 rounded-xl text-slate-300 bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800"
                onClick={() => setSession(false)}
              >
                Logout
              </Link>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you redirect in your Login component? The middleware just handles unauthenticated requests. You can navigate to dashboard after login with https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook

Comment: I am redirecting it to /home in the login component.But, after login if I click on /dashboard it again send me back to /login. Since, I am already authenticated it should not do that. I have noticed, It works after 5-10 minutes. I assume revalidate triggers and request reaches middleware again and then it redirects me to /dashboard. Also, If I logout, I allow me to navigate to /dashboard for some time even when I am logged out and after 5-10 minutes it will redirect me /login correctly. I believe it has something to do with caching but still trying to find the exact cause.

Comment: maybe you did not create sessiontoken correctly. `console.log(sessionToken)`

Comment: sessionToken is good otherwise even a delayed navigation won't work plus I don't see a request to /dashboard end point in the network tab. I believe that's the issue, looks like it is serving the cached response for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the way the NextJS Router-Cache works
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#router-cache

Basically, the first time you try and navigate to `/dashboard`, the page the actually loads is `/login` because of the middleware redirect. This is the page whose data gets cached by the Router-Cache for the `/dashboard` path. So when you try revisit `/dashboard` after logging in, the login page data is loaded again from the cache.

> Blockquote The Router Cache temporarily stores the React Server Component Payload in the browser for the duration of a user session... While the Full Route Cache only caches statically rendered routes, the Router Cache applies to both statically and dynamically rendered routes.

> Blockquote
> The cache is stored in the browser's temporary memory. Two factors determine how long the router cache lasts:
> **Session**: The cache persists across navigation. However, it's cleared on page refresh.
> **Automatic Invalidation Period**: The cache of an individual segment is automatically invalidated after a specific time. The duration depends on whether the route is statically or dynamically rendered:
> Dynamically Rendered: 30 seconds
> Statically Rendered: 5 minutes

Essentially, NextJS caches the page that is loaded after each call to `router.route(<path>)` for a given value of `<path>` in the Browser.
And the same is true for navigating with `Link` components.

Unfortunately this caching is not configurable in the NextJS App router.
There are a couple of ways to clear the cache though:

1. Call `router.refresh()` on the client side. (Note this will do a visible page refresh and call middleware again)
2. Use a server action and set/delete any cookie or use `revalidatePath`

See the docs for more info on the above